# Hiding ToolbarIcon in MAUI application

Tags: maui

In a MAUI application I have a toolbar item like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ToolbarItem 
       x:Name="ToolBarItemUpdate"
       Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"
       Text="Update" />
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

How can I hide this item? There is no `IsVisible` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple solution is to add or remove the item by modifying the `ToolbarItems` list in the code behind file:

```
ToolbarItems.Remove(ToolBarItemUpdate);
ToolbarItems.Add(ToolBarItemUpdate);
```

But if you want to use MVVM, it is not that easy. My solution binds the property to a hidden switch, that then makes a callback to the code behind controls the visibility. Would love to have a better solution :-) First, I have a toolbar item like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem 
            x:Name="ToolbarItemAlbumMode"
            Text="Show album"
            Order="Secondary"
            Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

And then my hidden switch:

```
<VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="False">
    <Switch 
        x:Name="ToolbarHelperAlbum"
        IsToggled="{Binding HasAlbum, Mode=OneWay}"
        Toggled="ToolbarHelper_ToggleChanged"
        />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

And then this in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    
    RefreshToolbarItems();
}

private void RefreshToolbarItems()
{
    SetToolbarItemVisibility(ToolbarItemAlbumMode, ViewModel.HasAlbum);
}

private void ToolbarHelper_ToggleChanged(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshToolbarItems();
}

public void SetToolbarItemVisibility(ToolbarItem toolbarItem, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Switch switchControl)
{
    SetToolbarItemVisibility(toolbarItem, switchControl.IsToggled);
}

public void SetToolbarItemVisibility(ToolbarItem toolbarItem, bool value)
{
    if (value && !ToolbarItems.Contains(toolbarItem))
    {
        ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);
    }
    else if (!value)
    {
        ToolbarItems.Remove(toolbarItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using your approach with an `IsVisible` property and it's not firing the `OnIsVisibleChanged`. (If I set the bindable property which manages the visiiblity to another element, like a Button or whatever, it does bind it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @EstebanChornet, I had forgot about this. I have another solution that is not nice, but I think it should work: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3701#issuecomment-1387340301. I will verify this myself in a few days and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might have simplier solution. You can try to use the Page lifecycle, expect that your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and add your ToolbarItem when it should be visible - on your condition in the viewModel.

So - if you have a Page, ToolbarItem, propertyName to be checked in propertyChangedHandler and the code deciding whether it should be visible, you can use following.
It is just a fast prototype:

```
    ToolbarItem MyActionToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem()
    {
        Text = Localization.LocalizationResource.MyActionText,
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            if (BindingContext is MySpecialViewModel viewModel)
            {
                viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }),
        Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
        Priority = 0,
        IconImageSource = new FontImageSource()
        {
            FontFamily = FontFamilies.FontAwesomeRegular,
            Glyph = FontAwesomeSymbols.HourglassHalf
        }
    };

    this.RegisterToolbarItem<MySpecialViewModel>(
        MyActionToolbarItem,
        nameof(MySpecialViewModel.IsMyActionVisible),
        (vm) => { return vm.IsMyActionVisible; }
        );
```

The extension class:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterToolbarItem<TViewModel>(
        this Page page, 
        ToolbarItem toolbarItem,
        string propertyName,
        Func<TViewModel, bool> isVisibleDelegate) where TViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedHandler = (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) => 
        {
            if (sender is TViewModel vm
                && e.PropertyName == propertyName)
            {
                if (isVisibleDelegate.Invoke(vm))
                {
                    page.ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    page.ToolbarItems.Remove(toolbarItem);
                }
            }
        };

        EventHandler appearingHandler = (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (page.BindingContext is INotifyPropertyChanged bindableObject)
            {
                bindableObject.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
            }
        };

        EventHandler disappearingHandler = null;
        
        disappearingHandler = (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            page.Appearing -= appearingHandler;
            page.Disappearing -= disappearingHandler;
        };

        if (page.BindingContext is INotifyPropertyChanged bindableObject)
        {
            bindableObject.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            page.Appearing += appearingHandler;
        }

        page.Disappearing += disappearingHandler;
    }
}
```